# Lines are not drawn in Kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

This is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Line

class MainWidget(Widget):
    v_l_s=.1
    v_l_n=7
    Vertical_lines=[]   
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.init_vertical_lines()
    def on_size(self,*args):
            self.update_vertical_lines()
    def init_vertical_lines(self):
        for num in range(0,self.v_l_n):
            self.Vertical_lines.append(Line())
    def update_vertical_lines(self):
        cener_x=int(self.width/2)
        before_lines=-(int(self.width/2))
        line_x=cener_x+before_lines*self.v_l_s
        for numb in range(0,self.v_l_n):
            with self.canvas:
                self.Vertical_lines[numb].points=[line_x,0,line_x,self.height]
            before_lines+=1
        
 

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

GameApp().run()
```

This  code  should  return 7 vertical lines but it  is  showing  nothing.  What should I  do  to  solve  it ?(Note-An error is coming in publishing the question so don't care about this Note)

Answer (score 0):

When you initially create the `Line()` instance, you are not doing in a canvas context. Just add `with self.canvas:` to the `init_vertical_lines()` method:

```
def init_vertical_lines(self):
    with self.canvas:
        for num in range(0, self.v_l_n):
            self.Vertical_lines.append(Line())
```

Your code will then draw the 7 lines, but they are all in the same place (that's a different issue).